# Replace EF Core service with instance instead of type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

In a non-ASP.NET environment (e.g. console programme, unit tests or `dotnet ef` CLI tool) I can replace EF Core services using `DbContextOptionsBuilder`:

```cs
builder.ReplaceService<IRelationalDatabaseCreator, MyCreator>();
builder.ReplaceService<IMigrationsAssembly, MyAssembly>();
```

For `MyCreator` or `MyAssembly`, it uses the **type** and its default constructor. How do I replace a service with an **instance** instead (that I can customize)?

Some (invalid) code to show what I mean:

```cs
var myCreator = new MyCreator("foo", 123);
builder.Replace<IRelationalDatabaseCreator>(myCreator);
```

Comment: Are you referring to the DbContextOptionsBuilder in EF core?

Comment: @DaveF Yes, updated post.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know a way to achieve what you want. Perhaps if you explain why you want to use a concrete instance I might be able to suggest an alternative approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I replace a service with an instance instead (that I can customize)?

You can't.

> For `MyCreator` or `MyAssembly`, it uses the type and its default constructor.

That's not quite correct (otherwise you won't be able to replace EF Core services with dependencies).

The specified service implementation type instance is resolved from DI container as any other, so you can use any existing constructor dependency injection mechanisms to configure it (for instance, similar to how EF Core provides configured `DbContextOptions` to the `DbContext` constructor). The only specific here is that these dependencies must be registered in the app service container (where the `DbContext` is registered) since the builder does not allow registering services.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I'm just confused about something. Say this is running in a console app or unit test or as design-time tool (e.g. in `DesignTimeContextFactory`) and there is no container. This is outside aspnet. I'm not sure I understand - does EF Core have its own built-in DI container?

Comment: Yes, it does.  If you look at the `ReplaceService` method summary, it says *"This method can only be used when EF is building and managing its **internal service provider**. If the service provider is being built externally and passed to
`UseInternalServiceProvider`, then replacement services should be configured on that service provider before it is passed to EF.* It's complicated in such scenarios, since building provider to pass to `UseInternalServiceProvider` requires calling methods which you normally don't.

Comment: Mind blown. I had no idea. So I can create my replacement service, add it to a custom container and pass that to EF. I'm going to look into that and it's probably a separate question so I won't complicate this one any more. Thanks for putting me onto the right path.